# iOS Webrtc - Crash in capturing local Video Stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc

I am trying to use webrtc libs from Google's repo. I followed the steps and created an individual project with instructions and code similar to APPRTC and I was able to get it working. I was able to conference between 2 devices. But when I try to integrate with an older project Webrtc crashes. The following are steps to reproduce the crash.

1. Initialize Peer connection factory
2. Try to create local video stream in main thread
3. App crashes

I am getting crash when I try to create VideoSource in the below snippet. Any tips or suggestion is appreciated.

```html
- (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrack {
  RTCVideoTrack *localVideoTrack = nil;
  if (_peerConnection && self.localMediaStream) {
    [_peerConnection removeStream:self.localMediaStream];
    self.localMediaStream=nil;
    self.localVideoTrack=nil;
    self.localAudioTrack=nil;
  }
  NSString *cameraID = nil;
  AVCaptureDevicePosition devicePosition;
  if (self.captureDevice == kWebrtcMediaCaptureDeviceFrontCam) {
    devicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
  }
  else{
    devicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
  }
  for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in
       [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
    if (captureDevice.position == devicePosition) {
      //[self configureCameraForHighestFrameRate:captureDevice];
      cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName];
      break;
    }
  }
  NSAssert(cameraID, @"Unable to get the front camera id");
  RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
  RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
  RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer
                                                      constraints:mediaConstraints];
  localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];
  return localVideoTrack;
}

And the crash log
```

```html
* thread #1: tid = 0x33125c, 0x320b9b2c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'
    frame #0: 0x320b9b2c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 24
    frame #1: 0x32137388 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 520
    frame #2: 0x3213826c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_cond_wait + 40
    frame #3: 0x00515230  `rtc::Event::Wait(int) + 160
  * frame #4: 0x003e4912  `webrtc::MethodCall2<webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface, rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::VideoSourceInterface>, cricket::VideoCapturer*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface const*>::Marshal(rtc::Thread*) + 46
    frame #5: 0x003e419c  `webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryProxy::CreateVideoSource(cricket::VideoCapturer*, webrtc::MediaConstraintsInterface const*) + 68
    frame #6: 0x00414470  `-[RTCPeerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:constraints:] + 192
    frame #7: 0x0001fc4e  `-[WebrtcManager createLocalVideoTrack](self=0x01896620, _cmd=0x0083e058) + 1662 at WebrtcManager.m:360
    frame #8: 0x0001ca96  `__40-[WebrtcManager initializeWebrtcManager]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 46 at WebrtcManager.m:46
    frame #9: 0x01420172 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
    frame #10: 0x0142015e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
    frame #11: 0x01423e44 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1512
    frame #12: 0x234ad608 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
    frame #13: 0x234abd08 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1512
    frame #14: 0x233f8200 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #15: 0x233f8012 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #16: 0x2ac91200 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #17: 0x26b9ca58 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #18: 0x00279f60  `main(argc=1, argv=0x00e37a78) + 132 at main.m:17
```

Comment: I try your solution but can not solve it. any other suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is to look into AppRTC code's thread model and replicate the same for your own app. This was advocated by the webrtc team to me when i raised the crash. It worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad! I was trying to create PeerConnectionFactory and LocalVideoTrack in worker thread! Problem solved when I moved those to main thread. I have uploaded apprtc version in [Apprtc-Swift](https://github.com/Mahabali/Apprtc-swift) with description on [this tutorial](https://mobilitysolutionsexpert.wordpress.com/)

Comment: how exactly you fixed the problem, please? I have similar. Thanks.

Comment: Create PeerConnectionFactory and Local video track in main thread. There are many ways to do that. Envelope your code in `dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_main,.. )` is one way.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but it was solved by adding two Info-plist values for camera and microphone permission prompt:

`Privacy - Microphone Usage Description`

`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`

The value is the string you want to appear in the permission prompt